# Compilation issue of Abiword : Strange conflict about bool and boolean with jpeg library

Tags: c++, gcc, boolean, g++, libjpeg

I am trying to compile Abiword-3.0.4 on MacOS 10.15.4 Catalina.

For this I have installed jpeg with Brew manager package.

Once got sources, `./configure` is ok and when I type `make`, I have the following error during compilation :

```
make[6]: Entering directory '/Users/fab/Downloads/abiword-3.0.4/src/af/util/xp'
  CXX      ut_jpeg.lo
  CXX      ut_test.lo
  CXX      ut_svg.lo
  CXX      ut_timer.lo
  CXX      ut_units.lo
  CXX      ut_unicode.lo
  CXX      ut_types.lo
  CXX      ut_uuid.lo
ut_jpeg.cpp:105:9: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'boolean' with an rvalue of type 'int'
        return 1; // boolean is a libjpeg type that is an int.
```

So I look for the line `return 1` into `ut_jpeg.cpp` file and I find at line 105 :

```
static boolean _jpegFillInputBuffer (j_decompress_ptr cinfo)
{
    bytebuf_jpeg_source_ptr src = reinterpret_cast<bytebuf_jpeg_source_ptr>(cinfo->src);

    // WARNING ! this assumes that the ByteBuf will NOT change during JPEG reading.
    src->pub.next_input_byte = src->sourceBuf->getPointer (src->pos);
    src->pub.bytes_in_buffer = src->sourceBuf->getLength ();

    return 1; // boolean is a libjpeg type that is an int.
    // OTHER ATTEMPTS
    //return true;
    //return TRUE;
}
```

You can see my 2 other attempts (return true and return TRUE), both generating an error.

However, in the file `/usr/local/include/lcms2.h`, the macros are well defined when I use `return TRUE` instead of `return 1` :

```
#ifndef FALSE
#       define FALSE 0
#endif
#ifndef TRUE
#       define TRUE  1
#endif
```

There seems to be a conflict with boolean which is a int libjpeg type.

How can I overcome this issue of compilation?

### Update

The problem is that I can't access to the definition of `boolean` type:

The following command returns nothing :

```
grep -rIHnw 'boolean' /usr/local/include/
```

and this another one gives :

```
grep -rIHnw 'boolean' /opt/local/include | grep jpeg

/opt/local/include/jpeglib.h:103:  boolean sent_table;      /* TRUE when table has been output */
/opt/local/include/jpeglib.h:119:  boolean sent_table;      /* TRUE when table has been output */
```

Maybe I don't look for the right directory ? However, issue comes from `jpeg` headers or library, doesn't it ?

Comment: Maybe you should look at this path /usr/local/Cellar/ or /usr/local/opt . The location you wrote isn't the correct path for brew installed packages

Comment: Can you check if there is a "jconfig.h"?
It becomes only int if there is no "HAVE_BOOLEAN" defined

See here:
#ifndef HAVE_BOOLEAN
typedef int boolean;
#endif

It is done in jmorecfg.j

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the macro `HAVE_BOOLEAN` is defined?

The file `jmorecfg.h` that is part of ijg-libjpeg specifically says it doesn't define `TRUE`/`FALSE` when `HAVE_BOOLEAN` is defined. Regardless, your tag says you're compiling in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), so you should probably just use `bool`, `true` and `false` instead of `boolean`, `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

[See `jmorecfg.h` here](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/ijg/blob/ff9491d4e0a06542ae82367183e4548664705d80/jmorecfg.h#L306).